# MongoDB, mongoose, update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Дорогие разработчики, есть вопрос.
Допустим, у нас есть модель из определенного количества юзеров и модель из товаров. Каждый юзер - объект, у этого объекта есть поля, корзина - одно из них. Внутри корзины - items, где лежат объекты товаров, добавленные в корзину. При удалении товара, не из корзины, приложение выдает ошибку, так как товара нет, а в корзине юзера он остался. Знаю, что у монгуса есть метод updateMany, я пробовал его, но он удаляет всю корзину у всех юзеров, а мне надо только один объект, тот товар, который я удалил.
роутер удаления товара: соответственно, передаю id удаляемой корзины и хочу удалить этот объект у всех пользователей.

```
router.post('/strat/remove', auth, async (req, res) => {

try { 

    console.log('req.session.user._id: ', req.session.user._id)
    console.log('req.body.id: ',req.body.id)
    await User.update(
        {}, 
        {"cart": { $pull: {"items": {"stratId" : req.body.id }}}},
        {multi: true}
        )

    await Strategy.deleteOne({
        _id: req.body.id,
    }).lean()
   
    
    res.redirect('/blog')
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

})

```
 const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose')
 const user = new Schema({
   email: {
      type: String,
       required: true
   },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
name: String,

// password: {
//     type: String,
//     required: true
// },
resetToken: String,
resetTokenExp: Date,
avatarUrl: String,
cart: 
    {
 items:
     [
        {
            count: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
                default: 1
            },
            
            stratId: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Strategy',
                required: true
            }
        }
    ]
}
,
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Всё, я решил роблему. я просто сделал фунцию  отображения корзины, которая будет фильтровать нулевые stratId)